How to rotate a single page and render new rotation using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer
Using the ngx-extended-pdf-viewer (v21) package for angular (v18), i am trying to rotate specific pages instead of the whole document if i use the built in rotation functions.
Has anyone achieved this yet?
 private _getPdfPage(pageNumber: number): PDFPageView | undefined {
    const pdfApplication = this.pdfNotificationService.onPDFJSInitSignal();

    if (pdfApplication) {
      return pdfApplication.pdfViewer._pages[pageNumber - 1];
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  rotatePage() {
    const mostVisiblePageNumber =
      this.pdfViewerService.getCurrentlyVisiblePageNumbers()[0];

    const page = this._getPdfPage(mostVisiblePageNumber);

    if (page == undefined) {
      this.notificationService.error(
        'Page Rotation Failed',
        'Unable to access pdf page.',
      );
    } else {
      // Calculate the next angle for the rotation
      let currentAngle = page.rotation;
      let nextAngle = currentAngle + 90;

      if (nextAngle == 360) {
        nextAngle = 0;
      }

      // Set the desired rotation (0, 90, 180, 270)
      console.log(currentAngle);
      console.log(nextAngle);
      page.rotation = nextAngle;
      page.pdfPageRotate = nextAngle;

      // render the page with rotation changes
      this.pdfViewerService.renderPage(page.id - 1);

      console.log(this.pdfViewerService.addPageToRenderQueue(page.id - 1));
    }
  }

Edit:  To clarify the current issue I am having;  If i add a console log and check the value of page.rotation after I have altered its value, the new value is reflected.  However the page is not visually rotated within the ngx-extended-pdf-viewer.

please share a stackblitz with the issue happening
